# SpringBoot Controller mapping to incorrect method

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, exception, controller

I have below 2 GET mappings in my controller:

```
1. @GetMapping("/department/{deptId}/employee/{employeeId}")
public String func1(@PathVariable(value = "deptId", required = true) String deptId, 
                    @PathVariable(value = "employeeId", required = true) String employeeId) { ... }
```

```
2. @GetMapping("/department/{deptId}/employee/{employeeId}/workLogs")
public String func2(@PathVariable(value = "deptId", required = true) String deptId, 
                    @PathVariable(value = "employeeId", required = true) String employeeId) { ... }
```

When I Fire the API as:

`GET http://localhost:8080/department/102/employee//workLogs` --> Keeping `employeeId` as blank, this call gets mapped to the first GetMapping (func1) and `employeeId` is calculated as `employeeId = "workLogs"`.

Hence, There is no exception thrown for missing path variable which was marked as required and call completed with 200 OK.

How to resolve this, so that it maps correctly to func2, and throws an exception for missing required path variable.

Comment: it is undetstandable, however how do u even expect to get worklog based on a blank employeeid? In any case to avoid this kind of problem jsut create a new Worklog controller with a getMethod for `/worklog/{employeeId} `

Comment: No I dont expect to get workLogs on blank employeeId. I expect an exception thrown here, as a required path param is missing @JAsgarov

Answer (score 1):

When you make a request
`http://localhost:8080/department/102/employee/workLogs`
This will be interpreted as `workLogs` being provided as the employeeId.

There's a couple ways to solve the problem.

- In `func1`, throw an exception if `employeeId.equals("workLogs")`
- set employeeId as an Int or Long, so that an exception will be thrown by default when `workLogs` is attempted to be parsed as an `employeeId`

But actually, calling `http://localhost:8080/department/102/employee//workLogs` with the double slash (`//`) should result in a 404 error. Try using version 5.3.15 of Spring if this isn't the case.

Comment: How to add this version in build.gradle?

Comment: You can check the [gradle reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_spring_boot_web_applications.html), or post a copy of your gradle file & I'll be able to help

Comment: When I give " id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5' " as 5.3.15, and build the gradle file, it is not able to find this version.